# Application runs on emulator but not in real device

Tags: android, debugging, emulation, device

I have developed an `android` application. After launching the app it show splash screen and the login and it perfetly works on **emulator** and on **real** **device**, but when i press skip option on **device** the application crashed but not in emulator. Here is logcat for error:

```
07-11 12:48:59.735: D/skia(4382): jpeg_decoder mode 1, config 6, w 640, h 1136, sample 

1, bsLength 142a5!!
07-11 12:49:01.589: D/libc-netbsd(4382): getaddrinfo: autolife.com.np get result from proxy >>
07-11 12:49:02.126: D/skia(4382): jpeg_decoder mode 1, config 6, w 640, h 1136, sample 1, bsLength f1ae!!
07-11 12:49:08.694: W/dalvikvm(4382): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 62: Landroid/app/ActionBar;.setHomeAsUpIndicator (I)V
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.ActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at np.com.autolife.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:41)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at np.com.autolife.AutoLifeNepal.onCreate(AutoLifeNepal.java:33)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-11 12:49:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(4382):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please anybody have already faced this problem? Please help me find out the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell me whether the answer below it correct for your problem.

Comment: your second method seems to be work but when i run the application after following your procedure it crass with same above error. And your first method can not help in my situation.

Comment: Sorry, but it have to work.. Can you post your code of your BaseActivity and theme you use? I think that you've done something wrong. If (after going with second solution) you have the exacly same stacktrace it means that you haven't removed your line that causes errors (setHomeAsUpIndicator).

Comment: Thank you for your response :) after applying your first method on BaseActivity it is perfectly working.

Comment: But please tell what is your minSdkVersion - and do you use ActionBarCompat? The first approach will work, but as I've mentioned it will not change this icon on API lower than 18 - so the icon remains unchanged. It means no crach but also no desired effect. You should go with the second option to set this icon from theme.

Comment: im using minimum sdk 10 but im going to change it to 11

Comment: Please test the second method again (after the like that was causing error is removed). Please also notice that if you use AppCompat library you need to extend from @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light and also include homeAsUpIndicator (without "android:") in your style. BTW why to support Honeycomb? It is dead - you can move right to API 14 and do not use any AppCompat lib then so you can use just a Holo theme as I posted in my origina answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your stacktrace log you can se **NoSuchMethodError** - it means that system is not able to find following method: **android.app.ActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator**

As mentioned in documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

Don't know exactly which one you are trying to use, but both:

```
setHomeAsUpIndicator(Drawable)
```

and

```
setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)
```

were added in **API level 18**.
This means that they wont be available on lower API versions. This is probably the reason for your issue - you are trying to execute this code on phone with lower API version (below JELLY_BEAN_MR2).

You have 2 options:

**I**. Check the API version before calling this method:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(int);
}
```

This will avoid crash, but won't take any effect on lower API versions - so you probably want to go with the second option to achieve your styling goals.

**II**. Instead of trying to set homeAsUpIndicator from code - you can do it safely from styles (because it is **available from API 11**) by adding "android:homeAsUpIndicator" attribute.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#homeAsUpIndicator

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_home_as_up_indocator</item>
</style>
```

Greetings.